# How do I make a Text widget wrap long text into multiple lines?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using a `Stepper` widget and I'm using a `Text` widget as the title parameter.

The string I use for my text is long, and I'd like it to wrap the text in multiple lines. How can I do that?

Here's the code I used to build this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Stepper(
          currentStep: currentStepIndex,
          onStepContinue: () => setState(() => currentStepIndex++),
          onStepTapped: (int index) => setState(() => currentStepIndex = index),
          steps: questions
              .map((String q) => Step(
                    title: Text(q),
                    content: QuestionWidget(),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      );
```

Here's what it currently looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but this is the only thing working for me.

Surround the Text widget with a Container and set the maximum width of it based on Screen size.

Screen size - 84 seems to be the minimum value to avoid overflow. I've tested it on 2 devices and is working fine.

```
steps: widget.questions
  .map(
    (String q) => Step(
      title: new Container(
        constraints: new BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 84),
        child: Text(q),
      ),
      content: new Container(),
    ),
  )
  .toList(),
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I'm wondering, do you know what `84` means here? Is there some constant for that?

Comment: It's just like a marin or padding of 84 pixels. I've tried with various values above and below it and 84 pixels is the lease required to avoid overflow

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! :-) 84, interessting number. I tried some others, but indeed 84 is the best!

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this, and this is the only thing that worked for me!

Comment: Flexible (child: Text('Some text here')) is better solution to wrap text in multiple line. Please try to use standard available widgets of Flutter. Do not recommend any calculation and hit & try solution. Deducting 84 is weird. Thanks

Comment: why is this the accepted answer? this may work but its like swapping your leg for a pogo stick, sure its roughly the right height but it is not a good idea

Comment: Thanks. This was the only solution worked for me

Answer (score 27):

Use [flexible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) if you just wanna make multiple lines:

```
Flexible (child: Text('Some text here'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the softWrap feature

```
child: Text("text",softWrap: true,),
```

Comment: The result looks the same with `softWrap` set to `true`.

Comment: because the lenght of he text is not yet long enough to go to new line. Wrap your text with Container, and set width so something lower

Comment: softWrap does not seem to work. I dont know why. Fleixble resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

you can  make use of the built in [Expanded Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) that takes the available space and switches to multiline if theres no space available horizontally/vertically it mainly depends on the parent widget. if the expanded widget is under row it will take the available space horizontally and if its under Column it will take the available space vertically.
heres the little code snippet showing the difference with output.

### Without Expanded it breaks the Screen

```
    Center(
       child: Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
             Text( // without expanded Widget breaks on right
                 'Hello World This is some long text,this will break the screen for sure')
           ]),
     );
```

### With Expanded Widget switches to multiline

```
   Center(
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                    'Hello World This is some long text,this wont break screen trust me,Some More Long tesxt a little more and more and more  and more......                     '),
              )
            ]),
      ));
```

Heres the Output With and Without expanded Widget

[image]
[image]